# Video stuck at single bitrate and not adapting with Exoplayer 2.6.1

Tags: android, azure, exoplayer

I am trying to implement Adaptive Video Streaming using Microsoft Azure on Android using Exoplayer 2.6.1.

The problem is, ExoPlayer automatically fetches a higher bitrate to play even if the connection is poor and keeps on buffering but does not switches to a lower bitrate.

But i am able to achieve adaptive streaming by using ExoPlayer 1.5.8.

Did ExoPlayer remove this feature on the newer version or am i missing something.

Also, is it safe to use previous version of ExoPlayer. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a workaround for your problem, but I have used it on Exoplayer 2.6.1. Also, Exoplayer 1.5.8 is an outdated version and has a lot of deprecated codes. The latest version is 2.8.1

```
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(PlayerActivity.this, btn_settings);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.Playback || menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.Quality) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.playbackGroup) {
                            // Was clicked on a sub menu item  in playback sub menu
                            mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlaybackParameters(new PlaybackParameters(playerSpeedSettings.get(menuItem.getItemId()), playerSpeedSettings.get(menuItem.getItemId())));
                            Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "" + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.qualityGroup) {
                            // was clicked on a sub menu item in quality sub menu
                            Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "" + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // For selecting the Quality Tracks
                            MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo info = ((MappingTrackSelector) trackSelector).getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();

                            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.onem) {
                                ((DefaultTrackSelector) trackSelector).setSelectionOverride(0, info.getTrackGroups(0), new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
                                        new FixedTrackSelection.Factory(),
                                        0,
                                        2
                                ));
                            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.sixk) {
                                ((DefaultTrackSelector) trackSelector).setSelectionOverride(0, info.getTrackGroups(0), new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
                                        new FixedTrackSelection.Factory(),
                                        0,
                                        1
                                ));
                            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.fourk) {
                                ((DefaultTrackSelector) trackSelector).setSelectionOverride(0, info.getTrackGroups(0), new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
                                        new FixedTrackSelection.Factory(),
                                        0,
                                        0
                                ));
                            } else {
                                ((DefaultTrackSelector) trackSelector).setSelectionOverride(0, info.getTrackGroups(0), new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(
                                        new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter),
                                        0,
                                        0
                                ));
                                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "" + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    return true;
```